Audio streaming from spring server
I hava a problem with audio streaming from my server.
The server get some file from another server with grpc, and get it chunk by chunk. After my server get this chunk i put it in outputstream, that delivery it to a client. And do it while outer server not complete this process.
I'm trying to play audio as it comes in, but the problem is that the client(chrome browser) starts playing audio only after full downloading, although in the debugger i can see that the bytes are flowing.
I hava a simple java(spring) server:
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/stream")
public class StreamRestController {

    private final GrpcServive grpcService = new GrpcServive();

    @GetMapping
    public void stream(final HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        StreamObserverPublisher streamObserverPublisher = new StreamObserverPublisher();
        final OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

        streamObserverPublisher.subscribe(new Flow.Subscriber<>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Flow.Subscription s) {
                // Ignored...
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(byte[] bytes) {
                try {
                    os.write(bytes);
                    response.flushBuffer();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                try {
                    os.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                throw new RuntimeException(t);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                try {
                    os.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });

        grpcService.synthesize(createRequest(), streamObserverPublisher);

        response.setStatus(200);
        response.setContentType("audio/wav");
        response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
        response.addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        response.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
        response.addHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
    }

    private Synthesis.SynthesisRequest createRequest() {
        return Synthesis.SynthesisRequest.newBuilder()
                .setText("One, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten.")
                .setContentType(TEXT)
                .setVoice("Kin_8000")
                .setAudioEncoding(WAV)
                .build();
    }
}

public class StreamObserverPublisher implements Flow.Publisher<byte[]>, StreamObserver<Synthesis.SynthesisResponse> {

    public Flow.Subscriber<? super byte[]> subscriber;

    @Override
    public void subscribe(Flow.Subscriber<? super byte[]> subscriber) {
        this.subscriber = subscriber;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Synthesis.SynthesisResponse response) {
        subscriber.onNext(response.getData().toByteArray());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
        subscriber.onError(throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        subscriber.onComplete();
    }
}

public class GrpcServive extends SmartSpeechGrpc.SmartSpeechImplBase {

    private final SslContext sslCtx;
    private final CallCredentials callCredentials;

    public GrpcServive() {
        try {
            sslCtx = GrpcSslContexts.forClient()
                    .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
                    .build();

            callCredentials = new BearerToken(
                    "token..."
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void synthesize(Synthesis.SynthesisRequest request,
                           StreamObserver<Synthesis.SynthesisResponse> responseObserver
    ) {
        ManagedChannel channel = NettyChannelBuilder.forTarget("host...")
                .sslContext(sslCtx)
                .enableRetry()
                .build();

        Iterator<Synthesis.SynthesisResponse> iterator = SmartSpeechGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel)
                .withCallCredentials(callCredentials)
                .withWaitForReady()
                .synthesize(request);

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            responseObserver.onNext(iterator.next());
        }
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

And a very simple client with thymeleaf:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>JavaScript Progress Monitor</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <audio controls preload="auto">
        <source src="/api/stream" type="audio/wav">
    </audio>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Are there any ways to solve it?

In this answer it was said that you needed to change the format of your wav file to enable streaming in the browser. If you can't get the remote service to send the wav file in a different format then you might have to manipulate it when you get hold of it at the server side. I don't know if this is more complicated than turning bytes 4-7 to and 40 - 43 to 0xFF (i.e. "setting ChunkSize to 0xFFFFFFFF and Subchunk2Size to 0xFFFFFFFF as well")

Just to check whether this is already the case, please could you print the first part of your output to the browser in hex?

full answer is too long for comment, but here is first 100 bytes of answer:
52 49 46 46 F7 FF FF FF 57 41 56 45 66 6D 74 20 10 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 40 1F 00 00 80 3E 00 00 02 00 10 00 64 61 74 61 D3 FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

If the other answer is right then you should facilitiate streaming by changing the four bytes following both 52 49 46 46 (== RIFF) and 64 61 74 61 (== data ) to FF. But I have attempted this and it doesn't seem to work for me in Chrome.

My advice is to specify that you receive the response in OGG format by changing the request to the speech synthesizer:

    private Synthesis.SynthesisRequest createRequest() {
        return Synthesis.SynthesisRequest.newBuilder()
                .setText("One, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten.")
                .setContentType(TEXT)
                .setVoice("Kin_8000")
                .setAudioEncoding(OPUS) // This is changed from WAV
                .build();
    }

This is assuming you are using this service and it still supports OGG.
You then need to change your content type to audio/ogg in the two places that you specify it:
response.setContentType("audio/ogg");

and
    <audio controls preload="auto">
        <source src="/api/stream" type="audio/ogg">
    </audio>

The reason I'm making this recommendation is that OGG is designed for streaming, while the specification for WAV requires that the file size is known in advance. I tried the solution from this answer to get Chrome to stream WAV files but it didn't work for me. In Firefox, on the other hand, WAV files played before being fully downloaded with or without the manipulation of the bits specifying chunk size.
But when I tested on an OGG file rather than a WAV file, the sound started playing in both Firefox and Chrome without waiting for the file to download.
